# Spark Rule of Thumb to estimate JOIN resource usage

Tags: join, apache-spark, rdd

I have two RDDs that I need to join where one of them is (150K, 25K) and the other one is (3M, 4). However, when I try to `rdd1.join(rdd2)` it takes a long time and error out with the message 'GC collection exceeded the limit'. I have already made the executor memory to be 16GB.

I guess here are my questions:

(1) What is the rule of thumb to adjust the executor memory size based on the data size

(2) For this type of matrix join, should I consider using EMR Spark so it can scale well without too much hassle or should I start using GPU since it handles matrix manipulation much better.... Any suggestion/idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Dataframe operations are always faster than RDD operations. Considering the executor memory size, since you are AWS, you can try monitoring your cluster with Ganglia and decide on how much RAM and CPU you need.

Comment: Just curious, 'GC collection exceeded the limit.' does not hit me as usual OOM for spark. Are you running it in self-contained or standalone cluster mode? If so, I believe, there are other factors aside from executor memory, most notably Java heap size. Also your data seems humble to hit OOM for 16gs.